# Cassandra: DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes and I am using DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy. The replication factor is 3 and READ/WRITE consistency level is QUORUM. Cassandra version 2.0.7 (both server and java client driver

I bring down 2 nodes reads are working but some writes are failing. My expectation is that WRITE also should succeed (especially when I am creating a new row in the database). I am expecting WRITE also to succeed. Below is the exception ? Is this due to the older version of Cassandra or is my understanding DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy wrong ? The exception seen in the logs is below. I am puzzled by Cassandra saying not enough replicas

13 Jul 2018 06:02:19 Manu a71e481b-d623-49dd-ba85-0ef7c85a05b7  [New I/O worker #6] INFO com.datastax.driver.core.policies.LoggingRetryPolicy - Retrying on unavailable exception at consistency ONE (initial consistency: QUORUM, required replica: 2, alive replica: 1, retries: 0)

13 Jul 2018 06:02:19 Manu a71e481b-d623-49dd-ba85-0ef7c85a05b7  [pool-18-thread-12] - Exception occurred during host create for application ManiAppNew in account a005d6db-6c65-42dc-b1d8-479d5912b83a

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

**O/P of nodetool status**

UN  10.117.113.133  427.86 KB  100.0%            19cca9a8-8a3c-43cc-be39-4180b826e5e6  -9178925427568840228                     rack1

DN  10.117.113.7    304.81 KB  100.0%            c594e31e-d4fc-461f-935f-0e59656cb7b4  -9158922850500536531                     rack1

DN  10.117.113.233  297.07 KB  100.0%            497fb5ec-3355-45f4-a9ce-4ccb1e04a4bd  -9173515640183044783                     rack1

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: Is ur cluster overload ? As 0 replica replied

Comment: No, It is not loaded. The last error is not enough replica, not sure why co-ordinator didn't consider itself .as a replica